# Looping through FileList declaration

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to wrap my mind around a particular for loop declaration, but I had no success so far. The code snippet allows you to read a file input and loop through all the objects thanks to a for loop:

```
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Now, I wonder when does this for loop

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
```

stops. Shouldn't the second parameter be a comparison parameter like " === , < , > " and so on ?

I can see that on each loop it is assigning to the variable 'f' the value of every object input in files[i], but I don't get why it is declared like that and how does it works. 
What is the difference between the aforementioned and this?

```
var f;
for (var i = 0;i<files.length; i++) {
      f = files[i];
}
```

Comment: It’s bad practice, but the `for` loop is still valid: `f = files[i]` is a statement that returns `files[i]`. This is used to “compare” or evaluate. It stops whenever that expression evaluates to `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigment always returns the assigned value, so the statement `f = files[i]` returns the file, which is a truthy value, until there are no more files in the fileList, then it returns `undefined`, which is falsy, and the loop stops.

The reason it stops is because a `for` loop consists of three expressions

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) { statement
```

The "condition" is an expression to be evaluated **before** each loop iteration.
 If this expression evaluates to true, the statement is executed, if it evaluates to false, like `undefined` would, the statement is not executed.